# How do I avoid my lowpoly mesh being all stretchy and weird in shade smooth?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, I'm learning 3d modeling, and I've become 10 years older in just a week. I love it.

I'm starting my journey by doing low-poly stuff. However, I've been encountering a problem

Every once in a while this happens:

[image]

Low-poly face looking pretty good so far. Yum yum. Let's add a low-poly nose.

[image]

meme_surprise_boom.mp3

That's obviously not supposed to happen, right?

Then I think to myself, "That must be because of the ngons! I've heard about ngons..." and I try to triangulate the mesh around the nose.

[image]

I tried triangulating those faces in every possible combination

[image]

To no avail. He still just looks angry.

[image]

I noticed that the model of Leon's face from RE2 I imported has the same weird stuff going on.

Any tips on how to fix that?

Thanks in advice

xoxo

Answer (score 0):

That's what supposed to happen, Blender will smooth between the triangles and give this result, if you want the shading to be more gradual you can give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, it will create virtual topology. Try to use quads rather than tris though, it will make the modeling easier.